# gem install knife-ec2 error

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I have installed a chef-server on a centos machine and I have also set up a workstation on another centos machine.

I have also set up the knife. Now I want to install knife-ec2 plug-in.

I am trying to install the knife plugin but getting the following error :

```
[root@ip-server-ip- chef-repo]# /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-ec2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
ERROR:  Error installing knife-ec2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for iconv.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
        --help
        --clean
        --use-system-libraries
        --enable-static
        --disable-static
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --enable-cross-build
        --disable-cross-build
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:103:in `have_iconv?'
        from extconf.rb:148:in `block (2 levels) in iconv_prefix'
        from extconf.rb:90:in `preserving_globals'
        from extconf.rb:143:in `block in iconv_prefix'
        from extconf.rb:116:in `block in each_iconv_idir'
        from extconf.rb:113:in `each'
        from extconf.rb:113:in `each_iconv_idir'
        from extconf.rb:137:in `iconv_prefix'
        from extconf.rb:424:in `block in <main>'
        from extconf.rb:161:in `block in process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:154:in `tap'
        from extconf.rb:154:in `process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:419:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

How to resolve this error.

Any lead is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Manny's answer is correct, but I wanted to also wanted to mention that [ChefDK is the recommended way to develop cookbooks](http://www.getchef.com/downloads/chef-dk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The knife-ec2 gem dependes on a gem called nokogiri.  The nokogiri gem is a binary and needs to be compiled when it is installed.  If you scroll down the error message you will see the following line:

```
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

It's just telling you to install gcc and make on your workstation.  In centos you can do this by running:

```
$ sudo yum groupinstall development-tools
```

This will get you everything you need to start compiling gem binaries.

If you are just starting out with chef I would actually recommend the chef development kit, [Chef-DK](http://www.getchef.com/downloads/chef-dk/).  It gives you all the tools you need to get started along with testing tools and helper commands to generate cookbooks.

Good Luck!

Comment: I have installed chef, workstation and chef knife. I just want to install plugin knife -ec2

Comment: this issue is resolved.now I am facing another issue : when I run knife client list WARNING: No knife configuration file found ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef/client.pem Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable How ever I have defined the path in the bash_profile also and have the knife.rb file in the /root/chef-repo/.chef. Please help me

Comment: This path `/root/chef-repo/.chef` will only work if you are working as root and if you are inside that directory running commands.  If you want to run knife commands from other directories you will have to have your knife.rb in ~/.chef.

Comment: I am still geting this error :knife user list
ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /root/chef-repo/.chef/bjyoti.pem
Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the following packages . I faced a similar error while installing .  My problem solved . It might help you .

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential  
sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential  
sudo apt-get install rubygems  ruby1.9.1
```

And then install knife ec-2 pluggin

```
$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-ec2
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am facing another issue : when I run  `knife client list
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef/client.pem
Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable` How ever I have defined the path in the bash_profile also and have the knife.rb file in the /root/chef-repo/.chef. Please help me

Comment: Please check once that the knife.rb file is there in .chef/knife.rb.

If not run the following command:

knife configure initial  so it will create knife.rb, then check the path of client key in knife.rb and cross check whether the client.pem is present on that location.

Comment: Yes the knife.rb is there !! if I do cd /root/chef-repo/.chef and then execute the list command it works but not from other locations.

Comment: did u copy the .pem files from /etc/chef to .chef folder .. ?? i mean admin.pem and chef-validator.pem

Comment: no i have copied the files from chef server itseflt, admin.pem and chef-validator.pem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55352/discussion-between-mohan-and-megha-sharma).